# Android Activity leaking Gridview

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-gridview, android-context

I have an activity with a gridview of images and captions. I've determined using MAT that this activity is leaking, but I'm not sure where I'm going wrong. Ignore any unused mentions of headers, I was previously using StickyGridHeaders GridView but switched to a normal GridView trying to figure out the problem.

**Activity Code**

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

ArrayList<String> imageUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> saleUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> captions = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<Sale> newSales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
ArrayList<Sale> endingSales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
Map<String, Integer> countForHeaders = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if(newSales.isEmpty() || endingSales.isEmpty()){
        Log.d("debug", "Fetching sales");
        String url = "https...my url";
        getJsonTask task =  new getJsonTask();
        task.execute(url);

        //Wait for urls before loading images
        try {
            task.get(10000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cover );

    GridView gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.cover_grid_view);

    gv.setAdapter(new MyViewAdapter(this, imageUrls, headers, countForHeaders,captions));

    //Click event
    gv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

            Log.d("debug","click " + saleUrls.get(position));

            Intent intent = new Intent(MyActivity.this, MyOtherActivity.class);
            ArrayList<Sale> sales = new ArrayList<Sale>();
            sales.addAll(newSales);
            sales.addAll(endingSales);
            intent.putExtra("sales", sales);
            intent.putExtra("position", position);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}


private class getJsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {        
        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            Log.d("debug","starting JSON task");
            return getJSON(urls[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } 
    }
}


private String getJSON(String myurl) throws IOException, JSONException{
    ...get image urls   
}
}
```

**Adapter Code**

```
final class MyViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private final Context context;
private final List<String> urls = new ArrayList<String>();
private final List<String> headers = new ArrayList<String>();
private final List<String> captions  = new ArrayList<String>();
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Map<String,Integer> countForHeaders = new HashMap<String,Integer>();


public CoverViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> urls, ArrayList<String> headers, Map<String,Integer> countForHeaders, ArrayList<String> captions) {
    this.context = context;
    this.captions.addAll(captions);
    this.headers.addAll(headers);
    this.urls.addAll(urls);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = convertView;

    if (view == null){
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_grid, null);
    }

    //Caption text
    TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_item_text);

    tv.setText(captions.get(position));
    tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    String url = new String (getItem(position));
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);

    //Get rid of extra vertical spacing
    iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso pic = Picasso.with(context); 
    pic.setDebugging(true);
    pic.load(url).into(iv);

    return view;
}

@Override public int getCount() {
    return urls.size();
}

@Override public String getItem(int position) {
    return urls.get(position);
}

@Override public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

}
```

[image: MAT path to gc]

Comment: You have far bigger problems, such as doing I/O on the main application thread. **Do not call `get()` on an `AsyncTask`**. That's why I have requested a Lint warning/error for this (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=57457). With respect to your supposed leak, MAT will point out to you what the GC root is that is preventing your activity from being garbage collected.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've added a screenshot of MAT's path to GC. It points to sDefaultWindowManager but I'm not sure what to make of that. With regards to your first point how would I ensure that I've fetched the image urls before setting the adapter without using get? Should I set the adapter in the AsyncTask's onPostExecute? If it would be more appropriate to respond to that in a new question let me know

Comment: "It points to sDefaultWindowManager but I'm not sure what to make of that" -- it feels like your activity is still on the screen. The window manager shouldn't be holding onto your activity otherwise. "How would I ensure that I've fetched the image urls before setting the adapter without using get?" -- set the adapter on the `GridView` in `onPostExecute()` of the task.